# Авторизация в ios с сохранением cookie

Tags: xcode, авторизация, ios, objective-c, ios7

Доброго времени суток!
Подскажите, ребята, как сделать авторизацию, чтобы я мог сохранить куки нескольких пользователей и чтобы была возможность перехода менду учетками этих пользователей.
Спасибо всем, кто отозвался.

Answer (score 1):

Сам не сталкивался с таким, но скорее всего нужно использовать '**NSUserDefaults**'